# div contents not vertically centering even though using display: table-cell

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to vertically center elements within a `div`, so per http://www.w3.org/Style/Examples/007/center.en.html, I set a `min-height`, `vertical-align: middle` and `display: table-cell`, but the text inside my `div` is still top-aligned.

```
<div id="fancybox-title-div" style="border: 1px solid black; min-height: 40px; display: table-cell; vertical-align: middle; width:50%; text-align: center; ">
    <div style="height: 50px; float: left; width: 25px; background-color: blue"></div>
    <div style="width: 70%">
    <span>text</span><br><a href="'+link+'" >view comments</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here's a jsFiddle for a visual:

http://jsfiddle.net/ccross59/gARYk/15/

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: u gotta float it.

http://jsfiddle.net/gARYk/10/

Comment: I'm not sure what you'd like the final result to look like.

Comment: I'd like both the text and the div next to it to be vertically centered within the wrapper div. Instead, it looks like the blue div is centered but the text isn't.

Comment: Is this good? http://jsfiddle.net/thirtydot/gARYk/19/

Comment: hm, @thirtydot, I'm having issues getting your code to work without the blue div: http://jsfiddle.net/ccross59/gARYk/24/ Any idea why?

Comment: This vertical centering technique relies on something such as that blue element being there. Does it need to work without the blue div? Also, do you only need to support modern browsers? Are you fine with dropping support for IE7?

Comment: it doesn't need to strictly speaking, but I'd like to know what about the blue element causes the vertical centering to work-- it doesn't seem to be height, or floating. I'd like to know so that if something like this comes up again, I will know how to fix it.

Comment: @thirtydot, for the reader's benefit, I think you should post that as an answer.

Comment: @Sparky672: I actually already did, but then I deleted it over the confusion with the blue element not being there. I'll undelete.

Comment: @Colleen: If in the future you don't have something similar to the blue element, you can switch to `display: table-cell; vertical-align: middle;` as in Jason Gennaro's answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the solution from my comment: http://jsfiddle.net/thirtydot/gARYk/26/

**HTML:**

```
<div id="fancybox-title-div">
    <div class="left"></div>
    <div class="right">
        <span>text</span><br /><a href="'+link+'" >view comments</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```css
#fancybox-title-div {
    border: 1px solid black;
    min-height: 40px;
    width: 50%;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}
#fancybox-title-div .left {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
    height: 50px;
    width: 25px;
    background-color: blue;
}
#fancybox-title-div .right {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
    width: 70%;
    border: 1px solid red;
}
```

If it matters, as it is this won't work in IE7. Here's a fixed version: http://jsfiddle.net/gARYk/27/

Comment: so I'm still confused as to what it is about the blue element that makes this work.

Comment: It's tricky to explain in a comment. This image might help: http://cdn.css-tricks.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/10/ghost.png. The relevant article is here: http://css-tricks.com/centering-in-the-unknown/. In my code, when `.left` is taller, it's the "ghost element" as shown in the picture. And when `.right` is taller, that takes over the role as the "ghost element".

Answer (score 1):

My understanding and the way it has always worked for me is that `display: table-cell` has to be inside another element (like a `div`) with `display: table`.

**Example:**

http://jsfiddle.net/495Rm/

**Example code:**

```
div#top{
    display:table;
    height:100px;
    border:1px solid red;
}

div#top{
    display:table-cell;
    vertical-align:middle;
}
```

Comment: it doesn't. I got it working by reverting back to display: table-cell, with no table wrapper div.

Comment: In your code @Colleen, you need a wrapper around `id="fancybox-title-div"` set to `display:table` or make the `div` to `display:table` and place the `display:table-cell` on the inside.

Answer (score -1):

[jsfiddle.net/gARYk/10](http://jsfiddle.net/gARYk/10) .... This is what you are looking for.

Comment: Ok, first of all, you just posted a link with no context. Second of all, I wouldn't have included an element unless I needed it there, so just deleting that element doesn't help me.

Comment: Learn to float lady.  jsfiddle.net/gARYk/10

Comment: Also, no, that's not the answer. If you reset the height on your wrapper div to something like 60px, you can see the text isn't centered. Even when float is added.

Comment: Thats a classic example of what HTML cannot do. Either you have to use javascript or give element height.

Comment: What? That comment doesn't make any sense.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/gARYk/16/ - even by setting wrapper 60px, it IS vertically aligned here.

Comment: The thing is you have to explicitly mention height if you want to vertically align something inside it.

Comment: no it isn't! Look at the distance between the top of the div and the top of the text, versus the bottom of the text and the bottom of the div.

Comment: I'm fine with explicitly setting a height, but that still isn't solving the problem.

Comment: Nope. Unnecessary. Have a look at thirtydot's solution.

Comment: srijan, please don't post links without any explanation. Answers should be fully self-contained. Otherwise, when your URL goes dead, the answer is meaningless.